# Is there any way to use http as redirect url for Box API?

Tags: box-api

I have created an application from Box developer account, but I couldn't able to set the redirect url as http. I have seen that Box API supports only https. As I hosted my web application as a module of another web application, I cannot change it's protocol to https. So is there any way to set the redirect url to http?

Please find me a solution for this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since the redirect URL is used to send you your application OAuth2 tokens, You are essentially asking Box to send you confidential information in the clear.  It's just not a good idea, since anyone that installs a network sniffer anywhere between you and Box can just sniff those tokens and start using them.

If you don't have the ability to ask your server hardware or hosting web application for an encrypted connection, it's probably time to upgrade your service provider or web app.